# How would you preprocess a field to print a different label?

Tags: 7, theming, entities

I have a field on a content type (let's call it Label1). I want the label to be displayed on the node, but I want to use Label2 as the label instead (without renaming the field). I am trying to preprocess the field using a preprocess field function, but am having trouble getting anything to work. Does anyone have any idea on how I would do this?

Also, I'm using D7.

Thanks!

Comment: Which Drupal version, `7` or `8`? as the answer will be different.

Comment: Oop, I should have specified - this is for D7.